# JSDoc: How do I document `var self = this;`?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

JSDoc is great at picking up on methods and properties defined on a class as long as you use the `this` keyword, e.g.:

```
/** @class */
function Person(name) {
  /** This person's name */
  this.name = name;

  /** Greet someone */
  this.greet = function(person) {
    return 'Hey there, '+person.name;
  };

  /** Log a greeting to the browser console */
  this.logGreeting = function(person) {
    console.log(this.greet(Person));
  };
}
```

This will generate docs with a "Class Person" page listing `name` as a Member and `greet()` and `logGreeting()` as Methods.

But when I have a complex case where I need to use the `self = this` pattern, things start to break:

```
/** @class */
function Person(name) {
  var self = this;

  /** This person's name */
  self.name = name;

  /** Greet someone */
  self.greet = function(person) {
    return 'Hey there, '+person.name;
  };

  /** Log a greeting to the browser console */
  self.logGreeting = function(person) {
    console.log(self.greet(Person));
  };

  /** Log a greeting to the browser console after some delay */
  self.logGreetingDelayed = function(person, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() { self.logGreeting(person); }, delay);
  };
}
```

This example generates a `Class Person` page, but it doesn't have the `name` member or any of the methods.

I've seen that you can use `@memberof` all over the place to manually attach each member and method to the class, but this is really verbose, and I was wondering whether there's a way to tell JSDoc that `self` refers to the class.

(Btw, I'm using JSDoc 3.4, in case that's important.)

Comment: Just FWIW, you *could* use `this` when defining those properties and only use `self` within the functions. But I can totally see what you're doing, if you're going for consistency in the code.

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder says, there's no need for `self` here at all. The only place you might think you need it, in the function passed to `setTimeout`, you could just say `setTimeout(() => this.logGreeting(person), delay)`.

Comment: @torazaburo: Well, the use case for the resulting object might be to use each of these as simple callbacks. If so, in ES2015, they could indeed be arrow functions: `this.logGreeting = person => { console.log(this.greet(person)); };` In ES5, `Function#bind` could do the same job: `this.logGreeting = function(person) { console.log(this.greet(person)); }.bind(this);` If that's not the use case, I don't see any reason not to put them on the prototype, which JSDoc is happy to handle.

Comment: I mean, sure, this is a trivial example, and it could easily be rearranged to avoid the need for `self`, but the point isn't the specific case here, it's the general concept. Feel free to mentally swap the `logGreetingDelayed()` function for a more complicated case in which you *couldn't* easily rearrange to get rid of `self`. As for why the methods are defined on `self` rather than just on `this`, sure, it's just a preference for readability's sake, but it's one that I've seen often enough in the wild that I thought it warranted a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@alias` annotation can be used to tell JSDoc to treat `self` as a reference to the class. Actually, technically, you need to alias `self` to the class's *prototype*, not just the name of the class itself (that breaks stuff in ways that I don't fully understand). To do this you need to set `@alias` to `Person#`<sup>1</sup>:

```
/** @class */
function Person(name) {
  /** @alias Person# */
  var self = this;

  /** This person's name */
  self.name = name;

  /** Greet someone */
  self.greet = function(person) {
    return 'Hey there, '+person.name;
  };

  /** Log a greeting to the browser console */
  self.logGreeting = function(person) {
    console.log(self.greet(Person));
  };

  /** Log a greeting to the browser console after some delay */
  self.logGreetingDelayed = function(person, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() { self.logGreeting(person); }, delay);
  };
}
```

---

**1:** Technically, `Person#` is equivalent to `Person.prototype`, since a trailing `#` refers to an object's prototype (as I understand it; open to correction). That being said, `this` actually refers to an instance, which is *not* the same as the prototype, so I recommend against using this notation, since it makes the comments more confusing. Fortunately, there's no difference in the JSDoc output between a prototype method and a true instance method, so don't worry too much about the `Person#` notation.

Alternative that works the same, included for completeness, but which should probably be avoided:

```
// ...

/** @alias Person.prototype */
var self = this;

// ...
```

Comment: That's misleading, though, surely, as those functions **aren't** on the prototype and their behavior relies on the fact they aren't. If you could really alias `self` to `this`, that would be great, but aliasing it to `Person#` seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're technically right that these methods are defined on an instance rather that the prototype (though... I don't see how they depend on this?), but as far as I can see, instance methods like these and true prototype methods are indistinguishable in JSDoc's output. I do agree, however, that the comments become clearer if you opt for the `Person#` notation rather than the `Person.prototype` notation, just to get the word `prototype` out of there.

Comment: *"I don't see how they depend on this?"* Prototype methods can be reused on other instances, directly (mixin-style) or indirectly (by creating a new prototype object using `Person.prototype` as its prototype and putting it on the `prototype` property of a new constructor). Those instance methods can't, they're tied to the specific instance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure, I understand the difference between instance and prototype methods, but you said that the behavior of the methods depends on their not being prototype methods, and I can't see how that's the case. Unless you just mean that they can't be called as mixins, which is mostly true I guess

Comment: The behavior I'm talking about is that they completely ignore `this`. Prototype methods don't.

Comment: In what way do they completely ignore `this`? If I rewrote `this.greet()` as: `this.greet = function(p){ return 'Hey '+p.name+' it\'s '+this.name; }`, that  works just as you would expect; `(new Person('Jake')).greet(new Person('Finn'))` returns "Hey Finn it's Jake". Instance methods know about `this` the same as prototype methods, far as I can tell. Or am I misunderstanding your point? (for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/1u1x3zas/)

Comment: I mean they ignore `this`. They use `self` instead. They can be called with a different `this`, and they won't use it, they'll use `self` instead. Prototype methods use the `this` they're called with, that's an important part of how they work. So, that's different behavior.

Comment: I don't want to keep this conversation going in the comments, so I'll stop after this. If what you're trying to say is that *these* methods, *the way I've written them here*, use `self` instead on `this` and couldn't be called with a different `this`, then sure, you're right. But if you're saying that *all* instance methods ignore `this` and can't be called with a different `this, you're incorrect on that point. Instance methods care about their `this` just the same as prototype methods do. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1u1x3zas/1/

Comment: Of course instance methods commonly use `this,` I never said they didn't. I'm saying *these methods, in the example* ignore `this`, and thus shouldn't be documented as prototype methods, which by definition use `this`. If you rewrote them to use `this` instead, then it might be appropriate to move them to the prototype (if it's not important for them to close over something in the constructor), and if you did, documenting them as prototype methods would be appropriate. But they don't work like prototype methods, thus documenting them as prototype methods is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this (pardon the pun) more complicated then it needs to be.  There are numerous problems with your design.

1. You don't need to use `this` to set prototypes. I greatly prefer to separate object `Instantiation` from `Initialization` paradigm like this:

   ```
   /** @class */
   function Person() {}

   Person.prototype =
   {
       /** This person's name
        * @return {Person}
        */
       init: function(name)
       {
           this.name = name;

           return this;
       },
   };
   ```
2. Greet *already* works on an object, you doesn't need pass in a 2nd object:

   ```
   /** Greet someone */
   greet: function() {
       return 'Hey there, '+this.name;
   },
   ```

   This also simplifies `logGreeting`:

   ```
   /** Log a greeting to the browser console */
   logGreeting: function() {
       console.log(this.greet());
   },
   ```
3. However, assuming you *do* want to pass in a *second* object (person) to your `logGreeting` it is incorrectly passing a `Class` and not an `Object`. It should be this:

   ```
   /** Greet someone */
   self.greet = function(person) {
     return 'Hey there, '+person.name;
   };

   /** Log a greeting to the browser console */
   self.logGreeting = function(person) {
     console.log(self.greet(person)); // BUG: was Person instead of person
   };
   ```
4. You shouldn't be using `self` to set prototypes -- you're mis-using the reason for using `self` in the first place: They are used for *callbacks* that need an object to refer to.

For example, let's add a callback when a person is renamed:

```
        rename: function(newName) {
            var self = this;
            var cbRename = function() {
                self.onRename( self.name, newName ); // Why self is needed
                self.name = newName;
            };

            setTimeout( cbRename, 1 );
        },

        /** Callback triggered on rename */
        onRename: function(oldName,newName) {
            console.log( "The person formally known as: '" + oldName + "'" );
            console.log( "Is now known as: '"              + newName + "'" );
        },
```

Putting it all together in an example:

```js
/** @class */
function Person() {}

Person.prototype =
{
    /** This person's name
     * @return {Person}
     */
    init: function(name)
    {
        this.name = name;

        return this;
    },

    /** Greet someone */
    greet: function() {
        return 'Hey there, '+this.name;
    },


    /** Log a greeting to the browser console */
    logGreeting: function() {
        console.log(this.greet());
    },

    rename: function(newName) {
        var self = this;
        var cbRename = function() {
            self.onRename( self.name, newName );
            self.name = newName;
        };

        setTimeout( cbRename, 1 );
    },

    /** Callback triggered on rename */
    onRename: function(oldName,newName) {
        console.log( "The person formally known as: '" + oldName + "'" );
        console.log( "Is now known as: '"              + newName + "'" );
    },
};

var alice = new Person().init( 'Alice' );
console.log( alice );
alice.logGreeting();
alice.rename( 'Bob' );
```

Which generates this JSdoc3 html:

```html
<div id="main">
    <h1 class="page-title">Class: Person</h1>
<section>
<header>
        <h2>Person</h2>
</header>
<article>
    <div class="container-overview">
<hr>
    <h4 class="name" id="Person"><span class="type-signature"></span>new Person<span class="signature">()</span><span class="type-signature"></span></h4>
<dl class="details">
    <dt class="tag-source">Source:</dt>
    <dd class="tag-source"><ul class="dummy"><li>
        <a href="person.js.html">person.js</a>, <a href="person.js.html#line2">line 2</a>
    </li></ul></dd>
</dl>
    </div>
        <h3 class="subsection-title">Methods</h3>
<hr>
    <h4 class="name" id="greet"><span class="type-signature"></span>greet<span class="signature">()</span><span class="type-signature"></span></h4>
<div class="description">
    Greet someone
</div>
<dl class="details">
    <dt class="tag-source">Source:</dt>
    <dd class="tag-source"><ul class="dummy"><li>
        <a href="person.js.html">person.js</a>, <a href="person.js.html#line17">line 17</a>
    </li></ul></dd>
</dl>
<hr>
    <h4 class="name" id="init"><span class="type-signature"></span>init<span class="signature">()</span><span class="type-signature"> → {<a href="Person.html">Person</a>}</span></h4>
<div class="description">
    This person's name
return {Person}
</div>
<dl class="details">
    <dt class="tag-source">Source:</dt>
    <dd class="tag-source"><ul class="dummy"><li>
        <a href="person.js.html">person.js</a>, <a href="person.js.html#line9">line 9</a>
    </li></ul></dd>
</dl>
<hr>
    <h4 class="name" id="logGreeting"><span class="type-signature"></span>logGreeting<span class="signature">()</span><span class="type-signature"></span></h4>
<div class="description">
    Log a greeting to the browser console
</div>
<dl class="details">
    <dt class="tag-source">Source:</dt>
    <dd class="tag-source"><ul class="dummy"><li>
        <a href="person.js.html">person.js</a>, <a href="person.js.html#line23">line 23</a>
    </li></ul></dd>
</dl>
<hr>
    <h4 class="name" id="onRename"><span class="type-signature"></span>onRename<span class="signature">()</span><span class="type-signature"></span></h4>
<div class="description">
    Callback triggered on rename
</div>
<dl class="details">
    <dt class="tag-source">Source:</dt>
    <dd class="tag-source"><ul class="dummy"><li>
        <a href="person.js.html">person.js</a>, <a href="person.js.html#line38">line 38</a>
    </li></ul></dd>
</dl>
</article>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Not only do you answer the user's question, but also illustrate:
1. How to improve their code
2. WHY it is improved this way
3. And put it all together

Fantastic answer!

Answer (score 0):

Why use a variable to receive `this` instead to use `this` with arrow function?

```js
/** @class */
function Person(name) {

  /** This person's name */
  this.name = name;

  /** Greet someone */
  this.greet = function(person) {
    return 'Hey there, '+person.name;
  };

  /** Log a greeting to the browser console */
  this.logGreeting = function(person) {
    console.log(this.greet(person));
  };

  /** Log a greeting to the browser console after some delay */
  this.logGreetingDelayed = function(person, delay) {
    setTimeout(() => this.logGreeting(person), delay);
  };
}
```

And if you want to document `this` (to use private methods for instance) you can use JSDoc `@this`:

```js
/** @class */
function Person(name) {

  /** This person's name */
  this.name = name;

  /** Greet someone */
  this.greet = function(person) {
    return 'Hey there, '+person.name;
  };

  /** Log a greeting to the browser console */
  this.logGreeting = function(person) {
    privateLogGreeting.call(this, person);
  };

  /** Log a greeting to the browser console after some delay */
  this.logGreetingDelayed = function(person, delay) {
    setTimeout(() => this.logGreeting(person), delay);
  };
}
//Private method
/**
 * @this Person
 * @param {Person} person
 */
function privateLogGreeting(person) {
  console.log(this.greet(person));
}
```